# Pdf Reader prints in console using java

Tags: java, pdf-reader

Hi guys I want to create a pdf reader which will read a hardcoded pdf and print data in console.I have used the below code..

```
public class pdfreader {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    readResourceFileAndPrintContents();
}

private static void readResourceFileAndPrintContents() throws Exception {
    InputStream stream = loadResourceAsStream("/home/ajay/Downloads/Beginning iPhone Development.pdf");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println((line));
    }
}

public static InputStream loadResourceAsStream(final String resourceName) {
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(resourceName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Resource File Not Found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return input;
}
```

}

But my I am not getting the context.
Can you please help me..Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have used iText but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java) you will find a couple library.

You need a library to extract strings, because the pdf isn't a text It is saved in a binary format. Need a library to decode.